# Angular: http post request - issue: "not found" even though api endpoint is in place

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web-development-server

I am trying to do a post request, where I include the JWT token in header. My problem is that when executing the request I get an error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/asdf", ok: false, …}
```

My request looks like this:

```
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };

    await this.http.post<any>(
      '/api/asdf', 
      httpOptions
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.usersFromBackEnd = data,
      console.log(data)
    });
```

The corresponding api-endpoint is:

```
app.get('/api/asdf', function(req, res){
    middleware.checkToken(req, res, next);
    handlers.index(req, res);
    console.log('asdf');
  });
```

My handlers.index() method is:

```
  index (req, res) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Index page'
    });
  }
```

My middleware.checktoken() method is:

```
let checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization']; // Express headers are auto converted to lowercase

  if (token) {
    if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      // Remove Bearer from string
      token = token.slice(7, token.length);
    }

    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Token is not valid'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Auth token is not supplied'
    });
  }
```

Note: the url snippet: `/api/asdf` is just a placeholder and will be replaced later on.

Could you help understand why I get this error and how I can resolve it?

Thank you very much in advance!
Best regards,
Samuel

EDIT: The error message contains localhost:4200, however, I think localhost:3000 should be called as is set it that way in my proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3000",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Also the terminal in VSCode logs:

```
[HPM] POST /api/asdf -> http://localhost:3000
```

Also I make other calls to the server side in the same way component, where I also only specify the code snippet with out the localhost adress. Please correct me if I am wrong - I am just starting out...

Comment: you called the wrong route, the route that you said is not defined on server that's why it's giving you 404 error.

Comment: did you add "Content-Type"?

Comment: @Sam, are you sure you have the correct API url? In my opinion you are trying to send a requst to the client side as of the fact showing url localhost:4200 which is a standard port for Angular.

Comment: @mamosek I think the right adress should be called - see edit of my question. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @AbuSufian I tried setting: ```` 'Content-Type':  'application/json'```` but that did not solve the problem...

Comment: The client is sending a POST request, yet the server is listening for a GET request?

Comment: @EricGuan Thank you so much! Thank was a really dumb mistake that I should have noticed myself, but now my code works! You really helped me here...